# SQL Server : Table instead of very complex view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Normally a full table from a view is created by:

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.table 
FROM view
```

But I have a very complex view (which worked in SQL Server 2005), but in SQL Server 2008 Express, I get the error message:

> Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please
>   look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to
>   simplify them.

By eliminating the header `<CREATE VIEW viewname AS>` I managed to do a normal query.
So I want to copy this query into a new table with all columns of the query.

The query (or the view) consists of 3 tables with a lot of joins and so on.

My question is, how is it possible to get my problem solved?

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.table 
FROM <here is my complex query, beginning with select>
```

does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583462/sql-error-expression-services-limit-reached

Comment: Since you'Re using `create table as select (CTAS)` have you tried using `insert into select`? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps :

First create your table with the appropriate column names and type.

Use then an INSERT INTO .... SELECT statement like this :

```
INSERT INTO yourNewTable
  (column1,
   column2,
   ...
  )
SELECT (your complex query)
```

Explicitely listing the columns is not mandatory if the result of your query directly match the structure of your target table. Nonetheless it is still advised for maintenability reasons.