# How do math functions affect the number of identifiers in an expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a calculation inside a case statement structured like this:

```
SQRT(POWER()+POWER()+...x84)
```

That's 84 power functions. I keep getting the error:

> Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

I understand the limit of identifiers in an expression is 65,535, but mine seemingly doesn't come even close to that. Do the functions change the effective number of identifiers in my expression?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full query if possible. It is not unthinkable that the problem is situated elsewhere.

Comment: That's not the only limit. Are you nesting those `POWER` clauses, by any chance? There are also operators/aggregates that internally duplicate expression trees, so you can hit limits earlier than you think. Per TT, post your whole query. The way you've simplified it now makes it *too* simple.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/913050/error-message-when-you-run-a-query-in-sql-server-2005-internal-error-a) old KB article may still be applicable. SQL Server doesn't seem to count the way the rest of us do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583462/sql-error-expression-services-limit-reached) question is a likely duplicate.