# ObjectSet from Entity Framwork is too big

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an ObjectSet called `AllTables` that includes tables Table1, table2, tabl3,... But now it's so big than when I try to make a select in AllTable I get the following exception

> SqlException: Internal error: An expression services limit has been
> reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your
> query, and try to simplify them.

That one is the query, `AllTables` is an entitySet that contains several entities. When you make a select over an entitySet, EF generates the query searching in all the entites those compose the setobject, creating a really big query that exceeds the 65000 characters

```cs
qGetByKey = CompiledQuery.Compile<EntitiesContext, Guid, Table>((context, key) => context.AllTables.FirstOrDefault(AT =>
AT.id.Equals(key)));
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: Error, Expression services limit reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583462/sql-error-expression-services-limit-reached)

Comment: No, I saw that question before but I don't have acces to the way that entity framwork creats the select joinning all the tables

Comment: You do. It's your own code that queries the *entities*. ORMs like EF Core deal with *entities* not tables. There are no JOINs, there are pre-configured relations between tables. A DbContext is not a model of the database or a database connection, it contains the entities used in a specific use case. The *client* code creates queries that get translated to SQL. If your code uses an overly complex query there may not be any way to translate it to SQL

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: qGetByKey = CompiledQuery.Compile<EntitiesContext, Guid, Table>( (context, key) => context.AllTables.FirstOrDefault(AT => AT.id.Equals(key)));

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the querie is auto-generated, so when I make a select the objectSet creates a select inside a select insed a select ... and with joins, the problem is that there are too many tables and I can't perform the querie becouse this one is auto-generated, so no, I can't have acces to this one in an easy way, if there is some way to perform the query is the question that I'm doing

Comment: Again, ORMs deal with entities and relations, not tables and joins. If you try to deal with them as if they were a model of the database you *will* run into such bugs. LINQ over EF is used to query entities, not replace SQL. If you misuse a tool, it will fail eventually. You still haven't posted the actual query though. `context.AllTables.FirstOrDefault(AT => AT.id==key);` is a very simple query. Unless `AllTables` hides a very complex query that tries to imitate a view. People can't help you fix a query when you don't post that query

Comment: If you have complex queries you can create a view that returns the results you want and map your entities to those views.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That one is the query, again, AllTables is an entitySet that contains several entities. When you make a select over a entitySet, EF generates the query searching in all the entites those compose the setobject, creating a really big query that exceeds the 65000 characters

Comment: Which is another way of saying that `AllTables` hides the real query. One so complex that `select top 1 * from AllTables where ID=@id` itself fails to execute, because whatever is behind that `AllTables` is more than 65000 characters. Again, if you misuse a tool it will break. If you have a query that's 65000 characters, you're *definitely* misusing EF. You've reached the point where you have to fix the bug instead of trying to bypass it. You may be able to clean up the query a bit so it becomes a little smaller, but that's still a misuse

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, that what i said at the first time and also I don't have access to the query, so again, I'm asking if there is some way to workaround of this.

Comment: No, your code finally crashed at 100mph. Which was inevitable, the moment someone decided that a 2000-character long query was acceptable

Comment: You *may* be able to get some breathing space by applying a SQL Server patch or update, or upgrading to a newer version, but the problem is the query, not SQL Server

Comment: The error you posted is [this SQL Server error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-8632-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15), not an EF error. As the error says, you should either simplify the query or break it up. If you want to merge results from multiple tables, query them separately, or in smaller batches, then merge the results in code

Comment: On the other hand, if I wanted to search every table in a database (a *very* unusual situation) I'd probably use [sp_MSforeachtable](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/) instead of trying to generate a huge UNION ALL query. If there was an inheritance relation between those tables, a separate `parent` table would be a far better idea. After all, that `context.AllTables.FirstOrDefault` can only work if the same results are returned from all tables. Or use an explicit loop to query those tables one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using EF will always become into a problem when performance is critical or it's needed a better control.

After try several options, I realized that the unique options to solve my problem are:

- Delete tables that I'm not using anymore.
- Create a method that makes the query to each entity that compose de entitySet independently. This solution improve the performance of the query.
- Use a microORM as Dapper at this case and another critical points wich require better performance, mantaining EF for the rest of the system. (This one is my favourite)