# Handling multiple users creating temp tables simultaneously

Tags: sql-server

I've got a report that will fire off a stored procedure on SQL Server. The report takes a couple minutes to run. Currently, in the development environment I'm writing to a couple of temp tables using this type of code:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp1
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyVal = 'X'

SELECT *
INTO #Temp2
FROM MyOtherTable
WHERE MyOtherVal = 'Y'

ETC...
```

Works fine in a dev environment, but there is a *slight* possibility that one day two people may kick this off at the same time with two different parameters. If they do, will that cause one `#Temp` to be overwritten? If so, what's the best way to handle that? Can you create a `#Temp` file name based on a timestamp or something?

Comment: No, Temp tables created the way you're showing are session specific.  Multiple users will not interfere with each other.

Comment: If the temp table begins with #, then it's specific to that user. If you give it a ## at the start, then it'd be global to all users.

Comment: Thanks, guys!  These are the pitfalls of being self-taught, but I'm always learning!

Comment: I was worried that connection pooling if you were using it, may cause some issues but it appears that's been considered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141718/sql-server-temp-tables-and-connection-pooling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temp Table usuage in a Multi User Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725812/temp-table-usuage-in-a-multi-user-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time I used temp tables, I wondered the same thing.  Try this experiment in SQL server.  In SSMS, run each of these queries and observe the results:

```
USE tempdb
GO

select * from sys.tables

SELECT * INTO #tablelist
FROM sys.tables

SELECT * INTO #tablelist2 
FROM sys.tables

-- The results of these two are different
SELECT * FROM #tablelist
SELECT * FROM #tablelist2
```

Look at the list of tables in your second query.  You will notice two tables named like `#tablelist_______ ... ____00007` and `#tablelist______ ... ____00008`.
This is how SQL server avoids name collisions for you.  The table it actually creates has a name that is similar to your temp table name, but with a sequence number at the end, to avoid name collisions.  It automatically handles this for you.